# Tkinter no encuentra mi imagen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy empezando a programar con python, pero al intentar utilizar **PhotoImage** para insertar una imagen en un **Label** me marca el siguiente error:

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "logo.png": no such file or directory.

He investigado en diversas fuentes y no logro conseguir una solución. La imagen que utilizo se encuentra en la misma carpeta que el archivo .py

El siguiente es todo mi código:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Control de Vacaciones")
root.resizable(True,True)
root.geometry("400x500")
root.config(bg = "gray")

Logo = Frame(root, width = 300, height = 150, bg="pink")
Logo.place(x = 50, y = 10)

miImagen = PhotoImage(file = "logo.png")
Label(Logo, image = miImagen, width=200, height=100).place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Pero el problema exactamente se encuentra aquí, al momento de utilizar `PhotoImage` junto con el `file`:

```
miImagen = PhotoImage(file = "logo.png")
Label(Logo, image = miImagen, width=200, height=100).place(x=0, y=0)
```

También lo intente de la siguiente forma, ya no me marca error pero la imagen no aparece:

```
imgPad = "logo.png"
miImagen = PhotoImage(imgPad)
Label(Logo, image = miImagen, width=200, height=100).place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: Pues no veo errores en tu código, intentaste con otra imagen??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta usando Pillow, tu código me funcionó bien cuando probé en *python 3.8*, de todas formas podría servirte lo siguiente: puedes revisar [La clase PhotoImage de Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) haré referencia de lo que se comenta en éste tema:

> Si necesita trabajar con otros formatos de archivo, Python Imaging Library (PIL) contiene clases que le permiten cargar imágenes en más de 30 formatos y convertirlas en objetos de imagen compatibles con Tkinter:
>
> ```
> from PIL import Image, ImageTk
>
> image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
> photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
> ```
>
> Puede utilizar una instancia de PhotoImage en cualquier lugar que Tkinter acepte un objeto de imagen. Un ejemplo:
>
> ```
> label = Label(image=photo)
> label.image = photo # mantenga una referencia!
> label.pack()
> ```
>
> Debe mantener una referencia al objeto de imagen en su programa Python, ya sea almacenándolo en una variable global o adjuntándolo a otro objeto.
>
> > **Nota:** Cuando Python recolecta basura en un objeto PhotoImage (por ejemplo, cuando regresa de una función que almacenó una imagen en una variable local), la imagen se borra incluso si está siendo mostrada por un widget Tkinter.
> >
> > Para evitar esto, el programa debe mantener una referencia adicional al objeto de imagen. Una forma sencilla de hacer esto es asignar la imagen a un atributo de widget, como este:
> >
> > ```
> > label = Label(image=photo)
> > label.image = photo # mantenga una referencia!
> > label.pack()
> > ```

Bueno una vez revisado lo anterior, lo que podrías probar seria algo así:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Control de Vacaciones")
root.resizable(True,True)
root.geometry("400x500")
root.config(bg = "gray")

Logo = Frame(root, width = 400, height = 200, bg="pink")
Logo.place(x = 50, y = 10)

miImagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "logo.png")
lbl = Label(Logo, image = miImagen, width=400, height=200).place(x=0, y=0)
lbl.image = miImagen
lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Espero te funcione. Saludos ;)

Comment: Tenia un erro similar. Estaba aprendiendo de un tutorial en video, lo que no entiendo es porque al chico del tutorial le funcionaron sus lineas de codigo pero a mi no, haciendo exactamente lo mismo. Tuve q cambiar mi codigo a lo q tu hiciste: label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo 
label.pack()                                                             Para que finalmente funcionara ._.

Comment: Podría ser la versión de python, como menciono en mi respuesta el código que OP tenia me funciona bien en python 3.8. Es muy posible que en tutorial que veias tuvieran una version especifica diferente a la tuya. ;)